# React router dom navigate method is not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Hei, I am trying to build a simple react app with a navigation feature. The main theme is I have 3 components, App, Test, and AppShell. **App** component is the default(Initial) component. And what I want is that **Every time user goes to App component, my app will redirect to Test component**.

The problem I am facing is that my redirection only works when I load the application the first time, after that my redirection is not working.

I am sharing my three components code below along with the index page!

**Index page**

```
    import './index.css';
    import App from './App';
    import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import {
        BrowserRouter as Router,
        Routes,
        Route
    } from "react-router-dom";

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Router>
          <Routes>
              <Route path='/' element={<App />} />
              <Route path='/test' element={<Test />} />
          </Routes>
      </Router>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );

    function Test() {
        return <h1>Test Me</h1>;
    }

    reportWebVitals();
```

**App Component**

```
import "./App.css";
import AppShell from "./components/core/appShell";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function App(props) {
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    return <AppShell {...props} navigate={navigate} />;
}
```

**App shell component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

class AppShell extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.navigate('/test');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>This is app shell</h1>
                <Outlet />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AppShell;
```

**I thought the problem is lies within component hooks, so I tried to implement the redirection inside the constructor too, but nothing is working for me!**

**The basic business problem I am trying to solve here is - A user will be redirected to a login page, every time he/she tries to browse another page regardless of valid login(valid user) could be based on the valid token on local storage**

Could anyone say, What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is `import { useNavigate } from 'eact-router-domr';`... the import package, a typo?

Comment: Yes, a typo. @DrewReese Fixed it.

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into a running codesandbox and see a warning about needing to call `navigate` in an `useEffect` hook and not on the initial render. Can you describe better the usecase you are trying to solve for?

Comment: @DrewReese Updated the question with the business problem I am trying to solve. Also, I don't know about any warning, as I am not getting any.

Comment: Based on your question update it seems you want/need to implement [route "authentication"](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/auth).

Comment: @DrewReese You are right, But the example is so complex to me, so I tried to just simplify it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Authentication with regards to protected routes is actually pretty trivial in `react-router-dom` v6

Create a wrapper component that accesses the auth context (local state, redux store, local storage, etc...) and based on the auth status renders an `Outlet` component for nested routes you want to protect, or a redirect to your auth endpoint.

Example `AuthWrapper`:

```
const AuthWrapper = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const token = !!JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"));

  return token ? (
    <Outlet />
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/login" replace state={{ from: location }} />
  );
};
```

Uses:

- `useLocation` hook to grab the current location user is attempting to access.
- `Outlet` component for nested protected routes.
- `Navigate` component for declarative navigation, sends the current `location` in route state so user can be redirected back after authenticating.

Example Usage:

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route element={<AuthWrapper />}>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Login - In the authentication handler, once authenticated, set the localStorage and navigate to the location that was passed in route state.

```
function Login() {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const { from = "/" } = state || {};

  const login = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(true));
    navigate(from);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Test Me</h1>
      <button type="button" onClick={login}>Log In</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-router-dom-navigate-method-is-not-working-properly]

Answer (score 0):

Use navigate method in useEffect like this shown below:

Imports

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
```

Use following code

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const [logged, setLogged] = useState(null);

const logout = () => {
   localStorage.clear();
   console.log("Logged out");
   setLogged(Math.random());
};

useEffect(() => {
  navigate("/login");
}, [logged]);
```